Is it illegal for a company to cross out the "To the order of" line on a check and change companies being paid?
Long title, but I wasn't sure how else to put this.  Basically, I paid a contractor to do some work.  They have two companies, one with assets, and one with no assets.  We'll call them:

Company A: No assets
Company B: Lots of assets

I wrote checks to company A and company B, but every time they went to cash the checks, they would scratch out my "TO THE ORDER OF: Company B" line on the check, and replace it with "Company A".  Well, I didn't know this was happening, but now as you probably guessed, I'm probably in a lawsuit with them.  50% of my checks were supposed to go to Company B, but as I said, they just scratched them out.  Some of these checks were "Official Checks" from the bank, where everything was typed out.  It doesn't seem right that they can just change who the checks are written to.
I know this is a lawyer matter, and I have contacted a lawyer, I'm just a bit worried and wanted to see what was the general consensus on a site like this.
To be clear, both of these companies are owned by the same people, they just commit fraud under the name of company A and B, but only accept money to Company A....apparently by altering checks.

I wrote checks to company A and company B - you wrote different checks to each, or you wrote one check to both companies with "and"? If the latter - why? It would be highly unlikely for two companies to have a joint account.

Was the cheque crossed? Did it have ‘not negotiable’ on it?

@littleadv I wrote two different checks, one to each company.

@trueCamelType then your attorney is going to have them both for breakfast, get some popcorn and enjoy the show.

My goodness, if that ain't shady then bears don't $hit in the woods. Gotta admire the infinite "wisdom" of such companies...

What country are you in?

Do you have the cashed, cancelled checks? How long ago are we talking? What I'm getting at is what you (or your lawyer, rather) is going to be able to prove.

I don't understand this.  You wrote a check to Company B and gave it to Company B.  If they pass it on to Company A, that's their choice.  Why does Company B (or A? you're not clear) have any claim that you've not done something correct?

@trueCamelType I'd really like to know how this concludes, if you won't mind replying at a later point in the future.

Side-stepping the question of legality of the ccheck modification: the fact that they did this is evidence that you can go after the assets of company A, even if the owner claims that company B is responsible.  It would likely be the case anyway but the idea that you can move money into a shell company and then stand there like the monopoly man with his pockets turned inside out is not a real thing.  It's close to sovereign citizen level inanity.

There's a significant confusion: you've written what Company A/B did, but you've not said what the bank did.  Did the bank cash the check and withdraw the funds from your account?  Or did the bank say "no, you can't cross the name out, we won't honor that check"?

@Teepeemm The bank cashed the check and withdrew the funds.  The bank cashed the check for company A even though the check was originally written to company B.

A Company B representative can just endorse the check over to Company A.  No change to the front of the check is required.

@tbrookside That's what make it shady. It appears that the owner is trying to avoid the money being part of company B's accounting.

No bank should honor the altered check; changing the payee is not permitted any more than changing the amount. Complain to your bank; it's their responsibility to work with the other bank to reject that check.
What the contractor could have done was deposit the check as written and then written their own check to the second company, or possibly endorsed the check over to the second company if their bank was willing to accept that.
What they should probably have done was return the check to you and ask you for a new check written to the appropriate account name.
If you owe them payment (I presume you did or you wouldn't have written the check), you do still owe them the payment. But this was not the right way for them to try to collect it.
(To address the headline question: If you want legal opinions you can trust, pay for consultation with a lawyer. But as a semi-informed and worthless opinion:  If they had tried to hide the change or make it appear to be your doing, that would presumably be fraud. Obviously altering it... I think that mostly qualifies as blatantly ignorant of how checks work.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The short answer is: lawyer. The long answer is: yes, and also lawyer.
It doesn't matter who owns the businesses you're paying, they can't unilaterally decide that someone different gets paid. Imagine a situation where they decided that you didn't pay what you owed to Company B because Company B never received a check. Or let's say I'm the sole owner of Company X - I can't change the payment from my company to myself because "I'm going to send it from my business account to my personal account anyway so this saves a step".
And let's say that you were actually supposed to pay (per your contract) Company A and not Company B. Doesn't matter. They should've told you to stop payment on the check, returned or destroyed the undeposited check, and requested a new payment with the correct information.
Note that there is a possible exception: endorsing a check and assigning it to a third party. However, endorsing a check doesn't allow any alterations to the front of the check, only the endorsement section on the back.

Also, as @keshlam suggested - the bank which cashed the check may also be liable

I imagine that the argument is something like "all OP's payments went to Company A and they're bankrupt so can't return the funds.  Company B shouldn't have to pay back money taken by Company A."  But if the contract was with Company B (we don't know) and the contractor accepted payment made out to Company B (they clearly did, even if they deposited the money to A), then Company B will be liable and can have its assets seized.

I take it signing the back of a check and handing it to somebody else is gone then. Because that's how you used to do this.

@Joshua that would mean that company B accepted the payment. I think the scheme the contractor is running is that all the payments go to A and it is the one liable, while it has no assets to seize if it is sued.

@littleadv: Which is clearly preposterous. Company B cannot disclaim liability for a payment simply by endorsing it over to company A. The payment was in fact made out to B, and B presumably accepted the payment at the time, so now B is liable for either returning the payment or providing the good/service that was contracted for. It would be crazy if you could just hand somebody else's money over to a third party and magically not be held responsible for it.

@Kevin right, exactly, that's why that's not what they did. Instead, they changed the original payee, so company B was never actually paid.

@Kevin, clearly it is preposterous; hence the first sentence of the answer.

@littleadv lol, but company b allowed the cheque to be given to company A - it was received by company b.

@fabspro no, actually, that's not what is described

@littleadv howso? the cheque was given to company b by delivery to its agent... the options are either company b permitted the cheque to be fraudulently altered (through company b's agent) or the contractor person fraudulently paid the cheque to another company. what do you consider to be the most reasonable analysis?

You're missing the point - this is exactly the fraud

No it is generally not illegal
We delve into the little understood law of negotiable instruments.

A negotiable instrument is a document guaranteeing the payment of a specific amount of money, either on demand, or at a set time, whose payer is usually named on the document. … The word "negotiable" refers to transferable and "instrument" refers to a document giving legal effect by the virtue of the law.

The key feature is that a negotiable instrument is transferable which mean the right to claim the payment(s) belongs to the holder in good faith - a term I’m not going to get into except to say it means someone who has the document and didn’t get it by nefarious means.
In modern usage, the most commonly known type of negotiable instrument is a government bond. The government promises to pay the coupon amount to whoever holds the bond when the coupon date comes around. However, historically, the most common kind was the cheque (or check).
The way it worked is like this. The lord of the manor has some work done and pays the contractor with a cheque for £1 drawn on a London bank. The contractor doesn’t have time to go to London so he negotiates to pay his timber supplier the 10 shillings he owes with the check and takes 10 shillings as change. The lumber mill owner, uses the check at the local store to buy provisions. The store owner uses it to buy stock. And so on. The £1 check drawn on the account of a very rich man that everybody in the local area knows is just as good as a £1 banknote. Eventually, someone is going to London and cashes the cheque. Or not. Or maybe someone uses it to pay their rent to the lord and he tears it up - being both the payer and the payee.
With the rise of modern banking systems, the ability for wire transfers, and the increased abundance of cash, this usage of cheques is uncommon - but it’s still legal.
Given your spelling of the word, I’m guessing you’re from the USA where the relevant law for checks and negotiable instruments is state based and usually but not always based Articles 3 and 4 of the Uniform Commercial Code (UCC).
There are ways of writing a check that make it not negotiable, but by default, they are freely transferrable.

Checks are endorsed over to a third party by a specific phrasing written on the back of the check and accompanied by a confirmable signature from the intermediate holder. In that specific manner, they are negotiable -- subject to the rules of the banks involved -- but the recipient must sign it over, not just deface the "to" line. You have a valid point, but I don't believe it applies in this case as described.

The problem is not that it was transferred by the original payee, but that the original payee has been changed without authorization

Also, you seem to be describing the situation from a perspective of a European. In the US it is radically different. There's no concept of "cross", or IBAN, or easy and quick wire transfers, and checks are very much in heavy use.

@littleadv: Right. They could have added a subsequent transaction by endorsing the check over, with proper trail of ownership. Instead, essentially, they took it up on themselves to singlehandedly rewrite the purchaser's instructions to their bank. If the check's author doesn't approve that change, the document becomes invalid and non negotiable. There are ways to legitimately do what they tried to do (if your bank trusts you enough to accept the cross-endorsed check). This was not one of them. I don't know that this specific instance rises to the level of fraud, or just incompetence.

(This is one reason I pay extra for duplicate checks. Physical evidence of what I actually wrote, should I need it. They're also more convenient for me to transcribe ledger from later than stubs were.)

Is this really how most cheques work in the UK?  My layman’s understanding (as I learned growing up in the 80s/90s, when cheques were still useful fairly often) is that a cheque made out to “bearer” did indeed function like this, but that a cheque made out to a specified payee (which was much more common) wasn’t transferable. The Wikipedia article you link seems to fit this, listing “bearer” and “cash” cheques specifically as examples of negotiable instruments.  I can well believe my layman’s understanding may be incorrect, but I’d like to see sources.

@littleadv yes, I always like visiting the USA - it’s like stepping in a Time Machine and going back 25 years.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine in the UK, and most of Europe/world, you can make checks non-negotiable by drawing a "cross" (two lines) on it. Most checks are now pre-printed with it. But there's no such concept in the US.

@DaleM if only we were so lucky. I worked in a European bank as a software person 25 years ago and the systems were more advanced then than any US bank is now.
